# Is there a way to capture mouse events on ParticleSystem or Sprite in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Tried ThreeX.domEvent (which uses Projector and Ray) but I presume there's no geometry for it to intersect. Any way to do a crude approximation? Eg. to set an imaginary Particle size, or even better, use the Sprite size? Thanks. (or am I just missing something?)

Comment: FYi: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/491